# How to type constructor functions that are properties of an object in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have an object with a property that is a constructor function. How do I type this correctly:

```
interface MyObj {
    constructor: () => ({ init: () => void })
}

const myObj = {
    constructor: function(this: any) {
        this.init = function() {
            this.var = 5;
        }
    }
}
```

This works without errors, but that's because I have the `this: any` in the constructor function. If I remove that I have the error

> Property 'init' does not exist on type '{ constructor: () => void; }'
>
> Property 'var' does not exist on type '{ constructor: () => void; }'

What is the correct way to type constructor functions like this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the keyword "new" to describe the type of constructor function

See example below:

First we define the constructor options interface

```
interface MyObjConfig<T> {
    init: (instance: T) => void;
}
```

Next is the interface for MyObj

```
interface MyObj<T> {
    constructor: new (config: MyObjConfig<T>) => T;
}
```

Now we create concrete implementations of MyObj and some test class

```
class MyObjItem {
    public var: number;
}

const myObj: MyObj<MyObjItem> = {
    constructor: MyObjItem
};
```

And now we can use myObj to construct new instances

```
const initiator = (instance: MyObjItem) => {
    instance.var = 5;
};


const concreteInstance = new myObj.constructor({ init: initiator });
```